# Custom TableViewCell with own different identifier

Tags: uitableview, identifier

I have tableview with custom prototype cells generated from array

```
cellLabel = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
             @"20 Последних новостей",
             @"Политика",
             @"Экономика",
             @"Право",
             @"Происшествия",
             @"Культура",
             @"Здоровье",
             @"Технологии",
             @"В Мире",
             @"Калейдоскоп",
             nil];
```

My question is How I can set own different reuseIdentifier for each cell while creating cells
Or I need to do 10 different cells?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellId = @"Sections";

sectionCell *Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellId];

if (!Cell) {

    Cell = [[sectionCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellId];

}

Cell.sectionTitle.text = [cellLabel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


return Cell;
```

}

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I would recommend using different reuse identifiers for every dynamically generated cell, but if you wanted, you could do something like the following:

```
 switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"1"];
            break;
        case 1:
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"2"];

        default:
            break;
    }
cell.textLabel.text = [cellLabel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: thank you, but with your option it shows white cells without label and image :(

Answer (score 0):

I was just confused. I am getting indexpath.row.So I can use row identifier for my code. Thanks anyway.

Comment: No problem. In the future, if you have a reply to an answer someone posted, just add it as a comment.